# .NET 6 encoding issue on Linux returning char * buf from shared lib

Tags: c#, .net-core

I have a `.NET 6 aspcore` app that loads an unmanaged dll. The dll returns C strings encoded as `ISO8859-1`.

Everything works fine with the Windows version but on Linux, any accented characters that come back are not translated into Unicode.

I've re-created the issue using a minimal dll & .NET console app.

The shared library code is a simple C file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

//file is ansi encoded 8859-1 é = xE9
static char* msg = "Montréal"; 

extern int Test(char* buf, int buf_size)
{
    if (buf != NULL && buf_size > (int)strlen(msg)) {
        strcpy(buf, msg);
        return ((int)strlen(buf));
    }
    return -1;
}
```

This is the .NET console app code. Note that I used `StringBuilder` to handle the char* buffer. I believe this is the typical way to do this.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

Console.WriteLine($"Hello,Montréal"); //utf8 encoded source file

var buf = new StringBuilder(512);
int ret = TestImport.Test(buf, 500);
Console.WriteLine($"Hello again, {buf.ToString()}");

public static class TestImport
{
    public const string _dll = "libTestLib.so";

    [DllImport(_dll, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern int Test( StringBuilder buf, int buf_size);

}
```

I'm running the app from WSL (Ubuntu 20.04) as:

```
$ dotnet run -c Debug -r linux-x64 --no-self-contained
```

Output shows as:

```
Hello, Montréal
Hello again, Montr�al
```

So how do I tell DllImport what the source encoding is? (ie CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)

Is there some .NET environment setting I'm missing?

Is there something I need to set up in the Linux environment? (I've tried changing the locale to `LANG=en_US.iso88591` - which doesn't seem to do anything)

I do have build ownership over the unmanaged dll, but it isn't going to return utf-8.

Comment: `Charset.Ansi` only supports UTF-8 on Linux, as that's presumed to be the "default" character set, much like Windows-1252 is on Windows (and note that that's *not* ISO 8859-1, though there's a strong resemblance). If you can't change your unmanaged code to use UTF-8, you'll have to marshal a byte buffer and explicitly decode it.

Comment: @JeroenMostert, Thanks for the quick reply, you wouldn't happen to have an MS link explaining this would you?  Will returning UTF-8 on WIndows work as well?

Comment: See [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/native-interop/charset). No, returning UTF-8 wouldn't work on Windows because `Charset.Ansi` means Windows-1252 there. If you want to get technical, and of course we do, `Charset.Ansi` may mean some *other* character set if the system uses a different default code page, but that's unusual. There appears to be [recent support for UTF-8 as the code page in Windows apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/apps/design/globalizing/use-utf8-code-page), but that's apps specifically, I'm not sure this would be possible for Win32.

Comment: Well, some trivial extra searching yields [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/windows/win32/sbscs/application-manifests#activeCodePage), so it indeed does appear to be possible to set the code page to UTF-8 by including it in the manifest. Of course using UTF-16 everywhere and using `Charset.Unicode` also always remains an option, as this requires no special overrides (but is admittedly more clunky on Linux).

Comment: @JeroenMostert Thanks again, it'll be easier for me to marshal the param conv myself then to return utf-8 from an 'extremely' legacy library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well taking @JeroenMostert's advice I'm going to marshal the params myself using a Byte[] buffer. Perhaps a custom marshaler would work - if I could figure it out.

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Text;

Console.WriteLine($"Hello,Montréal"); //utf8 encoded source file

var buf = new Byte(512);
int ret = TestImport.Test(buf, 500);
var s = Encoding.Latin1.GetString(buf); // Latin1 = 8859-1

Console.WriteLine($"Hello again, {s}");

public static class TestImport
{
    public const string _dll = "libTestLib.so";

    [DllImport(_dll, CharSet = CharSet.Ansi)]
    public static extern int Test( Byte[] buf, int buf_size);

}
```

output looks like

```
Hello,Montréal
Hello again, Montréal
```